# passing whole 1-D array through a pointer to a function in C and then taking the array inputs through it

Tags: arrays, function, pointers

I am facing a big problem while passing a pointer to an array. Please help me with this to pass pointer to whole array and  then taking value  to array.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init(int **p,int n)
{
    printf("Enter the array elements:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <n;i++) 
        scanf("%d",*p+i);
    
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter the size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int a[n];
    init(&a,n);
}
```

[I am getting this warning, but still its running when I run ./a.exe fie of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FiB6.png)

Comment: I think `int a[n]` wouldn't be compiled. It will cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of the code should be as follows.

```
void fun(int *arr, int n)
{  
}
int main()
{
   fun(arr, n);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to declare static array of dynamic length, like as `int a[n]`

Dynamic allocation is the solution.
And also don't forget to release it at last.

Try this.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void init(int *p,int n)
{
    printf("Enter the array elements:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i <n;i++) 
    scanf("%d", p+i);
    
}
int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("enter the size of array\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    int *a = new int[n];
    init(a,n);
    ...
    delete[] a;
    return 0;
}
```